# Why does the GMail API strip the doctype and comments from outgoing messages?

Tags: gmail-api

The Gmail [Message Send API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) appears to be stripping out doctype and HTML comments from outgoing messages.

## Repro

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
2. Scroll down to "Try it!"
3. Log in with OAuth
4. For "userId" enter: *me*
5. For "raw" enter the result of the following node script:

generateMessage.js

```
var email = "From: 'me'\r\n" +
  "To: bradvogel@outlook.com\r\n" +
  "Subject: Test Doctype\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
  "\r\n" +
  "<!doctype html>" +
  "<html><body>test <!--[if !mso]>hidden from outlook<!--<![endif]--> </body></html>";

var base64 = new Buffer(email).toString('base64');
var websafeBase64 = base64.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
console.log(websafeBase64);
```

## Actual result

When I view the raw message source from the email received at bradvogel@outlook.com, it comes through without the doctype or comments:

```
To: bradvogel@outlook.com
Subject: Test Doctype
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html><body>test  </body></html>

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038--
```

## Expected result

Notice the doctype below:

```
To: bradvogel@outlook.com
Subject: Test Doctype
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!doctype html>
<html><body>test <!--[if !mso]>hidden from outlook<!--<![endif]--> </body></html>

--089e0102fc52abed0a04ff355038--
```

## Notes

Sending the same message via SMTP preserves the entire message.

The doctype and comments are needed to format emails for Outlook and iOS Mail. The API appears to be taking my raw rfc822 message and converting it multipart/alternative with text and html representations, but with important content stripped out.

Does anyone know how to preserve doctype and comments in a message send through the Gmail Message Send api?

Comment: To add a bit more detail to Brad's question: not having `doctype` in the HTML email, causes iOS Mail to display the email in "Almost Standards" mode, which is like "Quirks Mode" rendering in old IE browsers. The only way I can find to trigger the "Standards" mode is to include a `doctype`, which is strangely stripped out when sending emails via the Gmail API.

Comment: What is `gmailclient` in this instance? Being able to run this locally would help.

Comment: Logan, updated the repro steps to be clearer. Thanks ;).

Comment: I reached out to the engineering team for more information on whether this behavior is intentional or not.

Comment: @BradVogel Hi, could you please post the code which sends the email? I'm having an issue connected to yours and I would like to see how you are sending it. Thx in advance!

Comment: I actually didn't get to writing code for it yet, since I was blocked by this issue when testing directly from their site.

Comment: An update from the Gmail Tech lead: "This sounds like the API is doing the same type of pre-processing of email messages that our web interface does (they go through the same servers), which is unfortunately inconsistent with what SMTP MSA does.  I'm not sure of why there's the discrepancy--it might be we're being too strict and we can stop, or it might be that MSA is being too loose and letting things through it shouldn't"

Answer (score 5):

This is likely just an API design decision. Filed in their issue tracker as https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3786&thanks=3786&ts=1427478929