# Why does the Gmail API randomly replace some characters in HTML emails in outgoing messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

In addition to the strange disappearing markup issue as noted in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979403/why-does-the-gmail-api-strip-the-doctype-and-comments-from-outgoing-messages), I'm also noticing weird encoding problems where some characters are replaced with random letters. This seem to happen when there are very long lines in the markup. Here are examples:

## Normal behavior

**Before processing of Gmail API**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Email Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: 'ff-tisa-web-pro, Georgia, serif;">Pinterest mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skateboard Intelligentsia food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bird on it Echo Park. Pinterest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**After processing of Gmail API** (via opening message in Gmail, and selecting `Show original`).

```
--001a1133f016eff52804ff2a2885
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Email Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style>Pinterest mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skateboard Intelligentsia food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bird on it Echo Park. Pinterest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray.</p>
  </body>
</html>


--001a1133f016eff52804ff2a2885--
```

In the above example, what happens is what we expected. Once the line-length of the `p` element is longer however, we get unusual behavior.

---

## Weird behavior

**Before processing of Gmail API**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Email Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-family: 'ff-tisa-web-pro, Georgia, serif;">Pinterest mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skateboard Intelligentsia food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bird on it Echo Park. Pinterest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray. Pinterest mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skateboard Intelligentsia food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bird on it Echo Park. Pinterest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**After processing of Gmail API** (via opening message in Gmail, and selecting `Show original`).

```
--001a1133547278e12e04ff2a28d8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=
=3D1.0">
    <title>Email Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style>Pinterest mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skat=
eboard Intelligentsia food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bir=
d on it Echo Park. Pinterest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray. Pinterest=
 mumblecore authentic stumptown, deep v slowcarb skateboard Intelligentsia =
food truck VHS. Asymmetrical swag raw denim put a bird on it Echo Park. Pin=
terest four loko lofi forage gentrify cray.</p>

  </body>
</html>


--001a1133547278e12e04ff2a28d8--
```

In the above example, the number of characters inside the `p` element has doubled. Somehow this triggers all sorts of weird encoding issues. Notice that `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` is added about the markup. Also notice that `3D` appears after every `=`. Also, hard line breaks have been added to the `p` element. At the end of each line there is an `=` sign.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't know how to prevent this but this very much looks like the format all my emails are stored in on my computer. (I'm using a client which uses a `Maildir` for storing messages.)

Comment: BTW: It's not only line breaks and equal signs that get escaped but also umlauts (try it for yourself: äöüß).

Comment: Ah, found a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) on that topic.

Comment: Are the emails rendering correctly? If so, than the exact transfer mechanism shouldn't be as important.

Answer (score 0):

Google storage the email using the standard RFC822, and in this specific case as you can see on the headers beside the Content-Type text/html you can find the header Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

So you need to parse the RFC822 message to get the actual html.

1. Find the correct chunk (the format of the message is like a multipart using the  boundary that you will find in the first headers
2. Parse the headers of the Chunk and to get the encode-type (not always its a quote-printable so be careful)
3. Using the encode of the previous step decode the body of the chunk

I hope this answer you question