# Apply MSO conditional statements when sending email via Gmail API

Tags: html, api, email, gmail, conditional-statements

I have been sending basic and more advanced HTML emails from multiple addresses in a GSuite account using PHP and SwiftMailer.

I have been sending these emails via SMTP, authenticating with a username and password. This means I need Gmail's Less Secure Apps (LSA) enabled on all the accounts. These emails have been displaying well everywhere as far as I know - including older versions of Outlook.

Ensuring the LSA setting stays turned on and that we have the latest account passwords in the system is enough of a reason to switch to the API method. Additionally, I've read that GSuite accounts would not be allowed to continue using the LSA method soon - it was already supposed to have happened but was delayed due to the pandemic.
https://9to5google.com/2019/12/17/g-suite-less-secure-apps/

I set up a mail service account in GSuite. I'm not using Swiftmailer for sending, opting for the Gmail 'quickstart' PHP library. This works with basic HTML-formatted emails. When I say basic, I'm talking about header and strong tags and a little inline css for font color.

The next goal is to send a more complex HTML email which includes more styling, embedded remote images and some MSO conditional statements. The emails are being sent and delivered. The MSO conditional statements, like other tags including MS-specific doctype stuff, appear to be stripped out when I view the HTML source of the email. This HTML was working with SwiftMailer and SMTP.

The emails still look great in Gmail, my Android email app and Thunderbird. They do not look correct in anything Microsoft that I have tried - Outlook 07 and Win 10 Mail so far. I probably don't need to worry about Outlook 07 anymore, but if Win 10 Mail doesn't work, my fear is Outlook 365 and such don't either.

If I cannot use these MSO conditional statements that would likely mean a new, simpler email template. According to everything I've read however, these conditions are valid.

Below is a HTML email I've been trying to send but the conditions either don't work or are being stripped. I've also included the Google service code I use to send the message.

I tried various encoding options, meta tags and various conditional tags I found here. It doesn't make sense that Google would strip things away with the API if it doesn't using SMTP. Perhaps the key is using Swiftmailer with the API - another rabbit hole I've been trying to avoid.

**The Code**

```
<?php               
    require_once 'Google/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';        
    
    $fromAddress = "validaccount@gsuite.com";
    
    $user_to_impersonate = $fromAddress;
    $sender = $user_to_impersonate;
                                                            
    putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_my_gmail_service_account_json_file");
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setSubject($sender);
    $client->setApplicationName("Quickstart");
    $client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose"]);
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);       
    
    $fromName = "Sender Name";
    $sender = "validaccount@gsuite.com";
    $toAddress = "me@me.com";
    $toName = "My Name";
    $replyName = "Sender Name";
    $replyAddress = "validaccount@gsuite.com";
        
    $subject = "API Test";
      
    $strBody .= '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    $strBody .= '<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">';
    $strBody .= '<head>';
    $strBody .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn\'t be necessary -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no,address=no,email=no,date=no,url=no"> <!-- Tell iOS not to automatically link certain text strings. -->
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
        <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light">';     
    $strBody .= '<title></title>';  
    $strBody .= '</head>';
        
    $strBody .= "<body>";
    
    $strBody .= '<![if !mso]>  HTML meant for non-Outlook clients but it shows up everywhere  <![endif]>';
    
    $strBody .= '<![if mso]>  HTML meant for Outlook clients only but it shows up everywhere  <![endif]>';
    
    $strBody .= '<!--[if mso]><!-->  I read this might work better, but again it shows up everywhere  <!--<![endif]-->';
    
    $strBody .= '<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> This had no affect either and shows up eveywhere <![endif]-->';
                
    $strBody .= "Everybody can see this";
    
    $strBody .= "</body></html>";
                                      
    $rawMsgStr = "From: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($fromName) . "?=<{$sender}>\r\n";
    $rawMsgStr .= "To: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($toName) . "?=<{$toAddress}>\r\n";
    $rawMsgStr .= "Reply-To: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($replyName) . "?=<{$replyAddress}>\r\n";
    
    $rawMsgStr .= "Subject: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=\r\n";
    $rawMsgStr .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    //$rawMsgStr .= "Content-Language: en-US;\r\n";
    $rawMsgStr .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\r";
    //$rawMsgStr .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
    //$rawMsgStr .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
    //$rawMsgStr .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n';
    $rawMsgStr .= "{$strBody}\r\n";           
  
    // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($rawMsgStr), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    //return $msg;        
    
    $service->users_messages->send($sender, $msg);        
    
    echo "Complete!";         
?>
```

**The Resulting Source (Outlook 2007)**

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no,address=no,email=no,date=no,url=no"> 
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
        <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light"><title></title></head><body>  HTML meant for non-Outlook clients but it shows up everywhere    HTML meant for Outlook clients only but it shows up everywhere    I read this might work better, but again it shows up everywhere  Everybody can see this</body></html>
```

**The Resulting HTML in Gmail (Thunderbird is very similar)**

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000dc4b5d05bf2b6835"

--000000000000dc4b5d05bf2b6835
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

 HTML meant for non-Outlook clients but it shows up everywhere HTML meant
for Outlook clients only but it shows up everywhere I read this might work
better, but again it shows up everywhere Everybody can see this

--000000000000dc4b5d05bf2b6835
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


<html lang=3D"en"><head><meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/h=
tml; charset=3DUTF-8">
=09    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width">=20
=09=09<meta http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Dedge">=20
=09=09<meta name=3D"x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> =20
=09=09<meta name=3D"format-detection" content=3D"telephone=3Dno,address=3Dn=
o,email=3Dno,date=3Dno,url=3Dno">=20
=09=09<meta name=3D"color-scheme" content=3D"light">
=09=09<meta name=3D"supported-color-schemes" content=3D"light"><title></tit=
le></head><body>  HTML meant for non-Outlook clients but it shows up everyw=
here    HTML meant for Outlook clients only but it shows up everywhere    I=
 read this might work better, but again it shows up everywhere  Everybody c=
an see this</body></html>

--000000000000dc4b5d05bf2b6835--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I eventually confirmed it I think. The Gmail API is stripping comments from HTML emails as well as simplifying the doctype tag by stripping out the MSO-related stuff. It's not just MSO conditions, it's any HTML comment in the body of the email. So, I guess this is a duplicate of the following, and as the OP in that thread recently discovered, this issue is not fixed and possibly by design in Google's eyes.

[Why does the GMail API strip the doctype and comments from outgoing messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979403/why-does-the-gmail-api-strip-the-doctype-and-comments-from-outgoing-messages)

In the end I designed a more-basic HTML template without any MSO conditions to get around the limitations.

Comment: This is upsetting :|